# How to render mustache using : external json that have function as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, mustache

I want to render [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) example. but I want to get data from external file.
I copy this data to "mydata.json" :

```
{
  "beatles": [
    { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Lennon" },
    { "firstName": "Paul", "lastName": "McCartney" },
    { "firstName": "George", "lastName": "Harrison" },
    { "firstName": "Ringo", "lastName": "Starr" }
  ],
  "name": function () {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}
```

I copy template to "template.html" :

```
{{#beatles}}
* {{name}}
{{/beatles}}
```

and render this files by this code :

```
$.get('template.html', function(template) 
{
    $.get('mydata.json',function(datas)
    {
        var rendered = Mustache.render(template, datas);
        $('#content').html(rendered);
    }
}
```

these codes not working until I remove function(s) from data file.

- I tried : different 'dataType' in JQuery ajax request.
- I tried : get data as text and then jQuery.parseJSON that data.
- I tried : regular and LAMBDA syntax in functions scripts.

but I cant solve this problem.

Comment: That isn't valid json. There are no functions or `this` in json. To verify...put it through an online validator

Comment: @charlietfl I know. but I want to use external data and external template together in  mustache.js

Comment: Well you need a different approach. Can use object properties to pass to a function in your js. Off top of my head something like `"name":{"combine": ["firstName", " ", "lastName"]}`. then write a parser function based on those properties

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for your reply . but I want to render more complex function.based MVC pattern. this is available in mustache . but I cant do that with external resource.

Comment: Something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/E1YVGtxbTIlCg6NZ55FD?p=preview

Comment: Alternative is use `eval()` but it has security risks and is highly frowned on

Comment: Or another alternative is use an object of functions in js and in your data just provide the reference key to that function

Comment: @charlietfl thanks a lot . very useful code. http://plnkr.co/edit/E1YVGtxbTIlCg6NZ55FD?p=preview

Comment: is just roughly thrown together but should give you a good idea how to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer .
AJAX request datatype must be 'script' to receive data as json and function together.